# Lighttpd url-rewrite regex

Tags: regex, facebook, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I have this incoming link from Facebook,

[`http://fatstone.tv/portfolio/10-firsts-of-wingsuiting/?fb_action_ids=10152289396001063&fb_action_types=og.likes`](http://fatstone.tv/portfolio/10-firsts-of-wingsuiting/?fb_action_ids=10152289396001063&fb_action_types=og.likes)

but this yields a 404 from Lighttpd.

Desired end-result is: [`http://fatstone.tv/portfolio/10-firsts-of-wingsuiting/`](http://fatstone.tv/portfolio/10-firsts-of-wingsuiting/)

I've tried

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "fb_action_ids" {
        url.redirect = (
                "^/(.*)" => "/$1"
        )
}
```

and

```
url.rewrite = (
    "^/(.*)\.(.+)$" => "$0",
    "^/(.+)/?$" => "/$1"
)
```

to no avail.

Can someone please help me out with the regex!?  I don't have any url's that need `/? arguments`, so a regex to just slice the url starting with the `?` would be sufficient, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern: `^(.+)\?.*$` (and simply replace with $1)

Note that this will *not* match URLs that are already formatted the way you want.  I'm not sure if that's a problem or something you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you expand on the "will not match already formatted url's" - do you mean mod.redirects?

Comment: What I meant was that if the input is simply `http://fatstone.tv/portfolio/10-firsts-of-wingsuiting/` for example, this regex won't match anything (because it expects to see a "?" in the string).  This could be an issue depending on how the rest of your code works.